# How is a font path added to urxvt when using .Xresources?

Tags: terminal, gentoo, fonts, rxvt

Using xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/terminus I'm able to subsequently start urxvt with the following command and get support for the font that I want (terminus):

```
urxvt -fn -*-terminus-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

However, how is this done in .Xresources? How do I specify how the font should be scaled in .Xresources?

This is a Gentoo system.

Simply trying the following don't seem to work:

```
URxvt*font: xft:terminus:pixelsize=26
```

As I understand it urxvt uses two font systems, XLFD and Fontconfig. The following link https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rxvt-unicode#Font attempts to explain some of this. However, even when I verbatim copy the examples they provide, it appears to have no effect at all on what fonts urxvt actually uses.

I believe it uses a default font, which looks very bad on my system.

I've tried to look for debug and verbose flags for urxvt, but its man page doesn't list any. A problem is that urxvt doesn't give any feedback even when starting urxvt from another terminal about what fonts it tries, and where it attempts to look for them.

I've tried fc-list to list available fonts. However, it is not clear to me if this lists fonts that will work with XLFD or Fontconfig. Nevertheless, I've tried just a few at random, again nothing happens.

Comment: did you remember to run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` every time you changed the file?

Comment: I am running xrdb after updating it. The problem has to be something else.

Comment: If you're still having troubles with this and you're willing to debug a bit more, what happens if you run `urxvt -fn xft:terminus:pixelsize=26`? The two ways you used to refer to fonts will use different fonts or at least the different font mechanisms. The first one (which you used with `-fn`) will try to use the bitmap font, the second one tries to load the font through `Xft`. Two questions would be 1) what's the output of `fc-match terminus`? 2) did you build `urxvt` with `Xft` (`USE=xft`)?

Comment: `fc-list` lists fonts for fontconfig (thus `Xft`), `xfontsel` will let you pick X11 bitmap fonts (`XLFD`). Putting in `.Xdefaults`  (or `.Xresources`) what you pass as an argument to the `-fn` option should work in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment, if you use `.Xresources`, you should run

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

after changing the file.  Alternatively, you could edit `~/.Xdefaults` (but the people who insist on using `xrdb` recommend not doing that).

Either way, your resource pattern works-for-me, as well as just this

```
urxvt -fn 'xft:terminus:pixelsize=20'
```

(the wildcards do not work for me).  Using `strace`, I can see which files are opened when looking for "Term" or "term"; you might find that useful as a debugging feature:

```
execve("/usr/bin/urxvt", ["urxvt", "-fn", "xft:terminus:pixelsize=25"], [/* 61 vars */]) = 0
read(7, "#! perl\n\nuse POSIX ();\n\nmy $term"..., 8192) = 1223
access("/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-enable-terminus.conf", R_OK) = 0
stat("/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-enable-terminus.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=254, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-enable-terminus.conf", O_RDONLY) = 9
open("/users/tom/.icons/default/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/icons/default/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/pixmaps/default/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/users/tom/.icons/oxy-black/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/icons/oxy-black/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
read(7, "/usr/build/xterm/xterm-325f (101"..., 2048) = 34
chown("/dev/pts/3", 0, 0)               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

The file with the font information is

```
/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-enable-terminus.conf
```

which (on my system) contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <selectfont>
    <acceptfont>
      <pattern>
        <patelt name="family"><string>terminus</string></patelt>
      </pattern>
    </acceptfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

`urxvt` doesn't *look* for a given font.  It sets up a call to fontconfig (via the Xft library written by Keith Packard).  You can read the source-code for `urxvt` and see how it does this:

- [src/rxvtfont.C](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/rxvtfont.C)
- [src/rxvttoolkit.C](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/rxvttoolkit.C)

One of the notable (mis)features of Xft with fontconfig is its lack of error reporting.  If it fails to find the font you *asked* for, it will proceed on to offer you its default font.  Using `strace`, you can at least see that the correct font configuration file was used.

Comment: It doesn't work, even with running xrdb after updates. But "URxvt*font: xft:terminus:pixelsize=26" in .Xresources is the correct syntax? If so, the problem must be something else.

Comment: With strace I can see that it opens stat("/usr/share/fonts/terminus", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0, however I don't see how this information helps.