# Can't get font to load in URxvt from .Xresources

Tags: x11, fonts, rxvt

I've been trying to change my font in URxvt to Overpass Mono, but I've been having some problems. I moved the font files to `/usr/share/fonts/` and ran `fc-cache -f` to scan for the fonts. The fonts are listed in `fc-list` as the following:

```
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Overpass-Mono/OverpassMono-SemiBold.ttf: Overpass Mono,Overpass Mono SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Overpass-Mono/OverpassMono-Light.ttf: Overpass Mono,Overpass Mono Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Overpass-Mono/OverpassMono-Bold.ttf: Overpass Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Overpass-Mono/OverpassMono-Regular.ttf: Overpass Mono:style=Regular
```

In my .Xresources file, I've written `URxvt.font: xft:Overpass Mono`, but when I load URxvt, the font is not displayed and it uses a default font instead. I'm not sure what the problem is, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` after updating it?

Comment: @JonasBerlin Yes, I've tried both running `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and restarting my computer, and neither have had an effect.

Comment: Wondering if this could be of some help to you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310134/how-is-a-font-path-added-to-urxvt-when-using-xresources